# Run jQuery function only if CSS class is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I made a simple jQuery function that trims text. I trigger it this way:

```
// JS
function truncate() {

   <! – Stuff to do -->

}
truncate();


// ...    


// HTML
<div class="Truncate" data-words="60">

    <! – Text to Trim -->

</div>
```

The problem is that the function gives me an error every time I load a page that doesn't have a DIV with the class 'Truncate' on it.

So I'd like to trigger it only when that `<div>` is there. 
Actually I'd like that the `<div>` itself triggers the function.

I know I can wrap it in an IF statement checking for the class, but I was wondering if with jQuery I can call it over a selector, something like:

```
$('.Truncate').myfunctionName() {
   my stuff
};
```

That is creative syntax, just to make you understand.

...Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you currently calling it? What error are you getting?

Comment: Sounds like a logic error within `truncate`.

Comment: Inside I'm doing a bunch of stuff that relies on the class .Truncate
But the problem is only caused by the fact that the function is called on every page. Otherwise everything is working fine. I just would like it's called only when that DIV with that class is there

Comment: `$.fn.truncate = truncate`, then you can run your example with `$('.Truncate').truncate()`

Comment: You should be able to .map (JS native) or .each (Jquery function) to apply your truncate function without the if. Essentially: $('.truncate').map(truncate) I can add some code if this will work?

Comment: yes that's another possibility, even though I wasn't going to turn it in a plugin. It's just a micro functionality. My curiosity was more toward how jQuery can call a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer If I got it right.

```js
function doStuff(elements) {
  console.log('doing stuff...');
}

$(function() {
  var truncates = $('.Truncate');

  if (truncates.length) { // here you validate if there is any element with that class
    doStuff(truncates);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Truncate"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. So is there only this way?
Cause I'm kind of newby with JS. I know that with vanilla JS you can call a function from an HTML element saying onload="myFunction()" so I thought with jQuery you could do something similar.

Comment: @rolfo85 - Ideally you want to keep your JavaScript separate from the HTML - I'm sure there's other ways you could do this, but the above is certainly one of the easiest.

Comment: When you define a selector in jQuery, it returns an array of the found objects. You could have something like: document.onload = findTruncates(); then in that func, place the above code.

Comment: Don't use document.onload with jquery, use jquery's document ready:  `$(function() { findTruncates(); });`

Comment: Ok so basically the IF is placed only where the function is called and not where the function is built. Does this make any differences?

Comment: @rolfo85 the way you did in your answer you were calling the jquery selector $('.Truncate') outside of ready function, it's the main difference here, because you would try to find something that could not be ready yet. The if where function is called is just a good practice, no real difference... It's cleaner and more readable

Comment: @rolfo85 The advantage of calling the `if` outside the function like is done in this answer is that you're preventing an additional function call if the element(s) are not found. It's slightly more efficient but on such a small order of magnitude that you won't notice it. Still, it's good practice to write efficient code...

Comment: Personally, I'd put the `if` inside the function rather than wrap it.  Next time you want to call that function you may not remember that it needs to be wrapped.  You also get lots of ifs everywhere rather than a single method call. ie maintainability over micro-managing efficiency.  (YMMV)

Comment: @freedomn-m this particular example I agree with you. However if doStuff function was called by other code parts that they don't need that if statement it would be bad to check it every time...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a js code with an IFEE function:

```js
(function(){
 var elmTranc=document.getElementsByClassName('Truncate');
  if(elmTranc){
    for(var i=0;i<elmTranc.length;i++){     
      elmTranc[i].innerHTML.trim();
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution using querySelector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

```
if(document.querySelector(".Truncate")){ //if element with .Truncate exists
  truncate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mini jquery plugin:

```js
// include jquery first

$.fn.truncate = function() {
  return $(this).each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 2));
  });
};

$(".truncate").truncate()
$(".someotherclass").truncate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='truncate'>Abc</div>
<div class='truncate'>Xyz</div>
<div class='notruncate'>123</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the end...

```
if( $('.Truncate').length ) {
    (function() {
        suff
    })();
}
```

Is it ok?